# Is there an actual listing (website, paper listing) of patent applications being published under the 18 month timeline?

Tags: publication, 18-month

I see sites like freepatentsonline has an online listing, but where do they get their listing from? Does the USPTO have a site with a listing of the 18 month publications?

For example, the most recent 18 month publications are here:
http://www.freepatentsonline.com/PD-07052018.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link below is official USPTO application publication site it's updated weekly on Thursday. To get the latest published applications of the week you need to input that Thursday date  in publication date section in YYYYMMDD format.

http://appft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html